# How to avoid excessive use of variables in XSLT by using call template or param or key?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to restructure my xslt with minimum use of variables. How can I achieve it?
Currently attribute 'Add' and 'Update' from higher parent node 'Books' forms the condition to construct the segments '' in the target xml.
Also in order to get the correct context, again variables are defined to the required segment 'Drama' to select correct Drama nodes with its attributes.
Now apart from 'Add' and 'Update', if I have 'Delete', 'PartialUpdate' etc...then I have to define many more variales to maintain the context... say more than 100 variables which is not manageable...also XSLT is running into pages... How can I use call-template or param or key or some other grouping mechanism to simplyfy my XSLT to get the required xml result.

Following is my sample input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
   <Library>
      <Books Id="A" Location="UK" Action="Add">
         <Section>
            <Drama Id="A1" Name="Short Play" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A1" Location="UK" Action="Update">ABC</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
            <Drama Id="A2" Name="Source Info" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A2" Location="UK" Action="Update">DEF</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
            <Drama Id="A3" Name="MFG Name" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A3" Location="UK" Action="Update">E and G</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
            <Drama Id="A4" Name="Book Material Group" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A4" Location="UK" Action="Update">0080</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
            <Drama Id="A5" Name="Book Number" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A5" Location="UK" Action="Update">121212</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
            <Drama Id="A6" Name="Book Material Description" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A6" Location="UK" Action="Update">Hard Page</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
            <Drama Id="A7" Name="Industry Sector" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A7" Location="UK" Action="Update">Printing</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
            <Drama Id="A8" Name="Book Material Text" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A8" Location="UK" Action="Update">Plastic coated</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
            <Drama Id="A9" Name="Book Material Type" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A9" Location="UK" Action="Update">INVT</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
            <Drama Id="A10" Name="Delete Indicator" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A10" Location="UK" Action="Update">Blank</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
            <Drama Id="A11" Name="UOM" Location="UK" Action="Update">
               <Values>
                  <Value Id="A11" Location="UK" Action="Update">M</Value>
               </Values>
            </Drama>
         </Section>
      </Books>
   </Library>
</Data>
```

The XSLT which I have developed with lots of variables is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <LIBRARY_DATA>
            <DATA_LIST>
<!--Assign variables with values from Books segment to use under child nodes-->
    <xsl:for-each select="Data/Library/Books">
                    <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Add'">
                        <xsl:variable name="vBooksAction"><xsl:value-of select="'Create_001'"/></xsl:variable>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Update'">
                        <xsl:variable name="vBooksAction"><xsl:value-of select="'Update_002'"/></xsl:variable>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Section/Drama">
                        <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Short Play'">
        <xsl:variable name="vShortPlay"><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Add'">
                                <xsl:variable name="vShortPlayAction"><xsl:value-of select="'Create_001'"/></xsl:variable>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Update'">
                                <xsl:variable name="vShortPlayAction"><xsl:value-of select="'Update_002'"/></xsl:variable>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Book Material'">
                            <xsl:variable name="vBookMtl"><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Add'">
                                <xsl:variable name="vBookMtlAction"><xsl:value-of select="'Create_001'"/></xsl:variable>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Update'">
                                <xsl:variable name="vBookMtlAction"><xsl:value-of select="'Update_002'"/></xsl:variable>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Delete Indicator'">
                            <xsl:variable name="vDeleteIndicator"><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></xsl:variable>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Book Number'">
                            <xsl:variable name="vBookNumber"><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Add'">
                                <xsl:variable name="vBookNumberAction"><xsl:value-of select="'Create_001'"/></xsl:variable>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Update'">
                                <xsl:variable name="vBookNumberAction"><xsl:value-of select="'Update_002'"/></xsl:variable>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Book Material Description'">
                            <xsl:variable name="vBookMtlDesc"><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></xsl:variable>
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Add'">
                                <xsl:variable name="vBookMtlDescAction"><xsl:value-of select="'Create_001'"/></xsl:variable>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Update'">
                                <xsl:variable name="vBookMtlDescAction"><xsl:value-of select="'Update_002'"/></xsl:variable>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
<!-- Constructing the segments with its field based on variable value-->
                    <BOOK_MATERIAL>
                        <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
                            <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
                            <xsl:if test="$vDeleteIndicator = 'Blank'">
                                <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Add'">
                                    <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Update'">
                                    <DATA_ACTION>Update_002</DATA_ACTION>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="$vDeleteIndicator != 'Blank'">
                                <DATA_ACTION>Delete_003</DATA_ACTION>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <FONT>Calibri</FONT>
                        <xsl:for-each select="Section/Drama">
                            <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Book Number'">
                                <BOOK_NUMBER><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></BOOK_NUMBER>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Delete Indicator'">
                                <xsl:for-each select="Values/Value">
                                    <xsl:if test="self::node()[text()='Blank']">
                                        <ASSIGN>Delete</ASSIGN>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Book Material Type' and @Location='UK'">
                                <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
                                    <MATERIAL_TYPE>Default</MATERIAL_TYPE>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
                                    <MATERIAL_TYPE><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></MATERIAL_TYPE>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Book Making Sector'">
                                <BM_SECTOR><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></BM_SECTOR>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Book Material Group' and @Location='UK'">
                                <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
                                    <BM_GROUP>Default</BM_GROUP>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
                                    <BM_GROUP><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></BM_GROUP>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Name = 'UOM'and @Location='UK'">
                                <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
                                    <BOOK_UOM>Numbers</BOOK_UOM>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
                                    <BOOK_UOM><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></BOOK_UOM>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Name = 'Part Number'">
                                <BOOK_PN><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></BOOK_PN>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Name = 'MFG Name'">
                                <BOOK_MFG>Default</BOOK_MFG>
                            </xsl:if>
                         </xsl:for-each>
                        <MTL_DETAIL>
                            <SPEC>Plastic</SPEC>
                            <LNG>EN</LNG>
                            <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
                                <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
                                <xsl:if test="$vDeleteIndicator = 'Blank'">
                                    <DATA_ACTION><xsl:value-of select="$vBookMtlDescAction" /></DATA_ACTION>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="$vDeleteIndicator != 'Blank'">
                                    <DATA_ACTION>Delete_003</DATA_ACTION>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <MTL_DEC><xsl:value-of select="$vBookMtlDesc" /></MTL_DEC>
                        </MTL_DETAIL>
                        <BOOK_TXT_HEADER>
                            <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
                                <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
                                <xsl:if test="$vDeleteIndicator = 'Blank'">
                                    <xsl:if test="$vBookNumberAction = 'Create_001'">
                                        <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="$vBookNumberAction = 'Update_002'">
                                        <DATA_ACTION>Update_002</DATA_ACTION>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="$vDeleteIndicator != 'Blank'">
                                    <DATA_ACTION>Delete_003</DATA_ACTION>
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <TXT_TYPE>Any</TXT_TYPE>
                            <TXT_OBJECT>MATERIAL</TXT_OBJECT>
                            <TXT_NAME><xsl:value-of select="$vBookNumber" /></TXT_NAME>
                            <BOOK_TXT_DETAIL>
                                <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
                                    <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
                                    <xsl:if test="$vDeleteIndicator = 'Blank'">
                                        <xsl:if test="$vBookNumberAction = 'Create_001'">
                                            <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                        <xsl:if test="$vBookNumberAction = 'Update_002'">
                                            <DATA_ACTION>Update_002</DATA_ACTION>
                                        </xsl:if>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                    <xsl:if test="$vDeleteIndicator != 'Blank'">
                                        <DATA_ACTION>Delete_003</DATA_ACTION>
                                    </xsl:if>
                                </xsl:if>
                                <TXT_FORMAT>Bold</TXT_FORMAT>
                                <TXT_LINE><xsl:value-of select="$vShortPlay" /></TXT_LINE>
                            </BOOK_TXT_DETAIL>
                        </BOOK_TXT_HEADER>
                    </BOOK_MATERIAL>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </DATA_LIST>
        </LIBRARY_DATA>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And after applying the XSLT, my required output xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LIBRARY_DATA>
   <DATA_LIST>
      <BOOK_MATERIAL>
         <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
         <FONT>Calibri</FONT>
         <BOOK_MFG>Default</BOOK_MFG>
         <BM_GROUP>0080</BM_GROUP>
         <BOOK_NUMBER>121212</BOOK_NUMBER>
         <MATERIAL_TYPE>INVT</MATERIAL_TYPE>
         <ASSIGN>Delete</ASSIGN>
         <BOOK_UOM>M</BOOK_UOM>
         <MTL_DETAIL>
            <SPEC>Plastic</SPEC>
            <LNG>EN</LNG>
            <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
            <MTL_DEC>Hard Page</MTL_DEC>
         </MTL_DETAIL>
         <BOOK_TXT_HEADER>
            <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
            <TXT_TYPE>Any</TXT_TYPE>
            <TXT_OBJECT>MATERIAL</TXT_OBJECT>
            <TXT_NAME>121212</TXT_NAME>
            <BOOK_TXT_DETAIL>
               <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
               <TXT_FORMAT>Bold</TXT_FORMAT>
               <TXT_LINE>ABC</TXT_LINE>
            </BOOK_TXT_DETAIL>
         </BOOK_TXT_HEADER>
      </BOOK_MATERIAL>
   </DATA_LIST>
</LIBRARY_DATA>
```

Also when the 'Delete Indicator' is not 'Blank' then  is not getting 'Delete_003' even if you are using the Variables since it is not resetting in every loop.

Please help me.

The complete modified XSLT code is shown below. I can start from here to include more complex requirement. Thanks @Kevin for your tips.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <LIBRARY_DATA>
            <DATA_LIST>
                <xsl:for-each select="Data/Library/Books">
                    <BOOK_MATERIAL>
                        <xsl:variable name="vBooksAction">
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Add'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'Create_001'"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Update'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'Update_002'"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <DATA_ACTION>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="@Action">
                                <xsl:with-param name="vBooksAction" select="$vBooksAction"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                        </DATA_ACTION>
                        <FONT>Calibri</FONT>
                        <BOOK_NUMBER>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Book Number']"/>
                        </BOOK_NUMBER>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Book Material Type' and @Location='UK']">
                            <xsl:with-param name="vBooksAction" select="$vBooksAction"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Book Making Sector']"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Book Material Group' and @Location='UK']">
                            <xsl:with-param name="vBooksAction" select="$vBooksAction"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'UOM' and @Location='UK']">
                            <xsl:with-param name="vBooksAction" select="$vBooksAction"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Part Number']"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'MFG Name']"/>
                        <MTL_DETAIL>
                            <SPEC>Plastic</SPEC>
                            <LNG>EN</LNG>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Delete Indicator']">
                                <xsl:with-param name="vBooksAction" select="$vBooksAction"/>
                            </xsl:apply-templates>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Book Material Description']"/>
                        </MTL_DETAIL>
                        <BOOK_TXT_HEADER>
                            <DATA_ACTION>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="@Action">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="vBooksAction" select="$vBooksAction"/>
                                </xsl:apply-templates>
                            </DATA_ACTION>
                            <TXT_TYPE>Any</TXT_TYPE>
                            <TXT_OBJECT>MATERIAL</TXT_OBJECT>
                            <TXT_NAME>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Book Number']"/>
                            </TXT_NAME>
                            <BOOK_TXT_DETAIL>
                                <DATA_ACTION>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@Action">
                                        <xsl:with-param name="vBooksAction" select="$vBooksAction"/>
                                    </xsl:apply-templates>
                                </DATA_ACTION>
                                <TXT_FORMAT>Bold</TXT_FORMAT>
                                <TXT_LINE>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Short Play']"/>
                                </TXT_LINE>
                            </BOOK_TXT_DETAIL>
                        </BOOK_TXT_HEADER>
                    </BOOK_MATERIAL>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </DATA_LIST>
        </LIBRARY_DATA>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match='@Action[parent::Books]'>
        <xsl:param name="vBooksAction"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$vBooksAction"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name='Book Number']">
        <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name = 'Book Material Type' and @Location='UK']">
        <xsl:param name="vBooksAction"/>
        <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
            <MATERIAL_TYPE>Default</MATERIAL_TYPE>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
            <MATERIAL_TYPE>
                <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/>
            </MATERIAL_TYPE>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name='Book Making Sector']">
        <BM_SECTOR>
            <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/>
        </BM_SECTOR>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name = 'Book Material Group' and @Location='UK']">
        <xsl:param name="vBooksAction"/>
        <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
            <BM_GROUP>Default</BM_GROUP>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
            <BM_GROUP>
                <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/>
            </BM_GROUP>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name = 'UOM' and @Location='UK']">
        <xsl:param name="vBooksAction"/>
        <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
            <BOOK_UOM>Numbers</BOOK_UOM>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
            <BOOK_UOM>
                <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/>
            </BOOK_UOM>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name='Part Number']">
        <BOOK_PN>
            <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/>
        </BOOK_PN>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name='MFG Name']">
        <BOOK_MFG>
            <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/>
        </BOOK_MFG>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name='Delete Indicator']">
        <xsl:param name="vBooksAction"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
                <xsl:for-each select="Values/Value">
                    <xsl:if test="self::node()[text()!='Blank']">
                        <DATA_ACTION>Delete_003</DATA_ACTION>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="self::node()[text()='Blank']">
                        <DATA_ACTION>Update_002</DATA_ACTION>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
                    <DATA_ACTION>Create_001</DATA_ACTION>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name='Book Material Description']">
        <MTL_DEC>
            <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/>
        </MTL_DEC>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name='Short Play']">
        <xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some inspiration that I think is cleaner. You have many problems In your XSL. Using templates and matching would be much easier to manage. You seem to need to use vBooksAction in several of them so that is the only variable I retained, but look at hos it is constructed. Not the way you did originally. Its a start for you to examine and finish. And I left it as you defined it, assuming your data could have something other than Add or Update. if not, it should not be two if's but rather a choose and otherwise.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        version="1.0">
        <xsl:template match="Books">
            <LIBRARY_DATA>
                <DATA_LIST>
                    <BOOK_MATERIAL>
                        <xsl:variable name="vBooksAction">
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Add'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'Create_001'"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="@Action = 'Update'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="'Update_002'"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@Action">
                           <xsl:with-param name="vBooksAction" select="$vBooksAction"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                        <FONT>Calibri</FONT>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Book Number']"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="Section/Drama[@Name = 'Book Material Type' and @Location='UK']">
                            <xsl:with-param name="vBooksAction" select="$vBooksAction"/>
                        </xsl:apply-templates>
                        <!-- Keep going here -->
                    </BOOK_MATERIAL>
                </DATA_LIST>
            </LIBRARY_DATA>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match='@Action[parent::Books]'>
            <xsl:param name="vBooksAction"/>
            <DATA_ACTION>
                <xsl:value-of select="$vBooksAction"/>
            </DATA_ACTION>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name='Book Number']">
            <BOOK_NUMBER><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></BOOK_NUMBER>
        </xsl:template>    
        <xsl:template match="Drama[@Name = 'Book Material Type' and @Location='UK']">
            <xsl:param name="vBooksAction"/>
            <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Update_002'">
                <MATERIAL_TYPE>Default</MATERIAL_TYPE>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="$vBooksAction = 'Create_001'">
                <MATERIAL_TYPE><xsl:value-of select="Values/Value"/></MATERIAL_TYPE>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the inspiration and tips to develop the code. I have modified the code to get multiple 'Books' records and also to handle the 'Delete Indicator' section.

Comment: I am facing another issue. Sometimes node 'Drama' with attribute 'Delete Indicator' will not exists. So how to handle such scenario? If node doesnt exists, I need to default <DATA_ACTION> with value 'Delete_003'. If the node 'Drama' with attribute 'Delete Indicator' exists then my xslt works perfectly.... Any tips?...

Comment: I have developed the xslt to handle the situation. Used a template which matches  "Section[not(Drama[@Name='Delete Indicator'])]" and defined the default values.

Comment: Excellent! That is what this site is for ... teaching. I am glad you managed that one!